# Get value from right with first white space

Tags: c#, .net, string

I want to get the value of the first white-space, from the right of a random string as below.

```
if my 
1. string = "sdsd sdsd sdsd 3232323"
or
2. string = "sdsd sdsd dseee3232323"
or
3.string = "sdsd dseee3232323"
or
4.string = "sdsd dseee3232323"

output :
1. 3232323
2. dseee3232323
3. dseee3232323
4. dseee3232323
```

Comment: given this example "asd asd123 asd" what would be the output? "asd123 asd" or "asd123"

Comment: Please show your attempts so far, even if incorrect

Comment: Looks like you are confusing 'space'  and 'white space'..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LastIndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.8) method:

```
string s = "sdsd sdsd sdsd 3232323";
var result = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

Comment: I Tried this Worked Thanks

Comment: Fails on empty string?

Comment: @dfhwze no, it returns empty string

Comment: OP has asked about white space not space character. Either a Regex os a list of white space characters is what is called for a correct solution..

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split) and [`LastOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault?view=netframework-4.8), just like this:

```
 var result = s.Split(' ').LastOrDefault();
```

Just don't forget to add the following to your using directives first:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq is not necessary.

```
String result = "";
String[] tempArray = workString.Split(' ');
if (tempArray.Length > 1)
     String result = temparray[tempArray.Length-1];
```

Split into an array and look at the last element.  I don't recommend using linq until you learn the basics.

Also I added a check to see if the result was invalid (no space).  If you don't have a space, the other answers will return the entire string.